# Find the root of a hierarchy, using Optional

Tags: java, option-type

I have a tree hierarchy of types that are aware of their children, but not their parents. Now I am creating an external registry that provides the opposite path, from the outside:

```
public interface Registry<X>{
    Optional<X> parent(X node);
}
```

Now I'd like to implement a method in that interface, that gets the root note of this hierarchy from any given node (the root node can be the node passed in or any ancestor).

I got this far:

```
default X root(X node) {

    X current = node;

    for (Optional<X> opt = Optional.of(current);
         opt.isPresent();
         opt = opt.flatMap(this::parent)) {

        if (opt.isPresent()) {
            current = opt.get();
        }
    }

    return current;

}
```

While this works, it feels kinda clumsy. `Optional.isPresent()` is called twice, and the variable `current` is re-assigned. Is there any way I can make this more elegant and functional?

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking of

```
default X root(X node) {
    X root = node;

    for (Optional<X> parentOpt = parent(root); parentOpt.isPresent(); root = parentOpt.get())
        ;

    return root;
}
```

I don't like dealing with `null` arguments. So we defer to `parent`'s implementation, which you'll probably document as returning an empty `Optional` on `null` argument.

If the argument is `null`, we'll also return `null`.

If the argument is not `null`, we save its value in `root` and start looping. We get its potential parent. If it's present, we update `root`, and retry. Otherwise, we break, and return the last saved value in `root`, since that's as far as we got.

That *clumsy* feeling, I think, comes from the initial `Optional` around `node`. I don't think you need that.

Comment: Yup, definitely cleaner than my original version, thanks. There's no way null will ever get here, so that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Guava and JDK stream versions below, but the absolute winner is [**JavaSlang**](http://www.javaslang.io/). I love it!

```
import javaslang.collection.Stream;
import java.util.Optional;
// ...
default X root(X node) {
    return Stream.iterate(Optional.of(node),
                              t -> t.flatMap(this::parent)
                         ).takeWhile(Optional::isPresent)
                          .last()
                          .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```

The `Stream.iterate()` method is exactly what I'm missing in the two other versions.

---

**[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):**

First we'll create a helper class called `Optionals`:

```
// to avoid misunderstandings:
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

import com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator;

public final class Optionals {

    private Optionals(){}

    /**
     * Given an instance of type T and a function from T to Optional&lt;T&gt;,
     * return an Iterable&lt;T&gt;. This Iterable will keep returning values
     * by repeatedly applying the supplied function until the returned Optional 
     * is not present.
     */
    public static <T> Iterable<T> stream(
        final T start, final Function<T, Optional<T>> increment) {

        return () -> new AbstractIterator<T>() {
            Optional<T> current = Optional.of(start);

            @Override
            protected T computeNext() {
                if (!current.isPresent()) return endOfData();
                final T data = current.get();
                current = current.flatMap(increment);
                return data;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is of course even more boilerplate, but that's re-usable, and now we can write the interface method in a concise way:

```
default X root(final X node) {
    return Iterables.getLast(Optionals.stream(node, this::parent));
}
```

Obviously it would be possible to implement this without Guava, but it would be a lot messier.

---

**Java 8 Stream version:**

```
public final class Streams {
    private Streams(){}

/**
 * Given an instance of type T and a function from T to Optional&lt;T&gt;,
 * return a Stream&lt;T&gt;. This Stream will keep returning values by
 * repeatedly applying the supplied function until the returned Optional
 * is not present.
 */
public static <X> Stream<X> stream(
        final X start, final Function<X, Optional<X>> increment) {

    return StreamSupport.stream(
            new Spliterator<X>() {

                Optional<X> next = Optional.ofNullable(start);

                @Override
                public boolean tryAdvance(final Consumer<? super X> action) {
                    final boolean present = next.isPresent();
                    if (present) action.accept(next.get());
                    next = next.flatMap(increment);
                    return present;
                }

                @Override
                public Spliterator<X> trySplit() { return null; }

                @Override
                public long estimateSize() { return Long.MAX_VALUE; }

                @Override
                public int characteristics() { return Spliterator.ORDERED; }
            }, false
    );
}
```

Which leads to this code:

```
default X root(final X node) {
    return Streams.stream(node, this::parent)
                  .reduce((left, right) -> right)
                  .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Sotirios is concise and more than good enough.

You implemented an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) in your attempt at a solution and my solution is to implement it as a [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)/[Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).   It's probably overly complicated for your particular question, but it could be useful elsewhere for your library, or it could be useful for someone else browsing stackoverflow.

```
public class ParentSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
    private final Registry<T> registry;
    private Optional<T> currentNodeOpt;

    public ParentSpliterator(Registry<T> registry, T startNode) {
        this.registry = registry;
        this.currentNodeOpt = Optional.of(startNode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (!currentNodeOpt.isPresent()) {
            return false; // stream is empty
        } else {
            T currentNode = currentNodeOpt.get();
            action.accept(currentNode);
            currentNodeOpt = registry.parent(currentNode);
            return true;
        }

//        // Alternative implementation (more Stream-ish):        
//        return currentNodeOpt.map(node -> {
//            action.accept(node);
//            currentNodeOpt = registry.parent(node);
//            return node;
//        }).isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        return null;  // Cannot be split.
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE; // No quick way to estimate size.
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return Spliterator.ORDERED; // maybe others?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Registry.CountDownRegistry cdr = new Registry.CountDownRegistry();
        ParentSpliterator<Integer> parentSpliterator = new ParentSpliterator<>(cdr, 3);
        Stream<Integer> stream = StreamSupport.stream(parentSpliterator, false);
        //stream.forEach(System.out::println);

        // Using a reduce to pick the last element of the Stream:
        Integer root = stream.reduce((node, nextNode) -> nextNode).get();
        System.out.println(root);
    }
}
```

And you need this utility class to get the example to work:

```
public interface Registry<X> {
    Optional<X> parent(X node);

    public static class CountDownRegistry implements Registry<Integer> {

        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> parent(Integer node) {
            if (node > 0) {
                return Optional.of(node - 1);
            } else {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at my updated version, I also switched to implementing the Spliterator directly :-). I don't like your approach of tying the streaming functionality and the parent together, that's tight coupling I'm trying to avoid. But I do very much like your "more Stream-ish" code. Why'd you comment it out?

Comment: It's awkward: a map operation that returns itself (does nothing), but that is needed for a double side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close already with the loop you tried. It can be simplified a bit since the loop body is only executed if the loop condition is true, so you don't have to retest `opt.isPresent` within the loop. You can save a variable if you reuse the `node` parameter. (I know, it's a style thing.) The `flatMap` call in the increment part doesn't buy you much because you know that `opt` is present at that point; you might as well just call `parent` on the result of `opt.get` while assigning `node` while you're at it. This gives:

```
default X root(X node) {
    for (Optional<X> opt = Optional.of(node); opt.isPresent(); opt = parent(node = opt.get()))
        ;
    return node;
}
```

You pretty much have to assume that `node` is non-null, so you can move the `parent` call into the loop condition, simplifying things a bit:

```
default X root(X node) {
    for (Optional<X> opt; (opt = parent(node)).isPresent(); node = opt.get())
        ;
    return node;
}
```

Java 9 will have a new [three-arg `Stream.iterate` factory](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) that lets you create a leaf-to-root stream of nodes quite conveniently. The three arguments are just like the three statements of a for-loop, except they can't have side effects. You can transliterate your original for-loop into a stream as follows:

```
default Stream<X> stream(X node) {
    return Stream.iterate(Optional.of(node),
                          Optional::isPresent,
                          op -> op.flatMap(this::parent))
                 .map(Optional::get);
}
```

Finally, there is this:

```
default X root(X node) {
    return Optional.of(node).flatMap(this::parent).map(this::root).orElse(node);
}
```

There are several things of note regarding this technique.

- It violates one of the style rules for `Optional` that I've been espousing, in particular this one: "#4: It's generally a bad idea to create an `Optional` for the specific purpose of chaining methods from it to get a value." ([link](https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/vjug24-session-on-optional/))
- It's recursive, which means it can blow your stack if your hierarchy is too deep.
- Your coworkers will shun you if you use this technique.

I don't recommend writing code like this, but I wanted to put it out there before somebody else did. :-)